# Only last index value is getting inserted into the excel sheet

Tags: java, selenium

I am trying to write data into excel through the web tables.
starting rows get created with blank data and last row is filled with data, with last index value.
other rows are not getting filled with data even when data is present in the `Arraylist`.

```
public class Write_Excel {    
    public static `FileInputStream` `fis`;    
    public static FileOutputStream fos;     
    public static `HSSFWorkbook` `wb`;     
    public static `HSSFSheet` `sheet`;      
    public static `HSSFCell` `cell`;
    public static `HSSFRow` `row`;
    public static `int a = 0`; 

public static void write_Excel(String fileName, String sheetName,
            `ArrayList`<String> `dataToWrite`) throws `IOException` {
    fos = new `FileOutputStream(fileName);
    wb = new HSSFWorkbook();
    sheet = `wb.createSheet(sheetName);`
    `row = sheet.createRow(a++);`
    for (int i = 0; i < 16; i++) {  
      cell = row.createCell(i);
      System.out.println(dataToWrite.get(i).toString());
      cell.setCellValue(new HSSFRichTextString(dataToWrite.get(i)));
        }
    wb.write(fos);
    fos.flush();
    }
}
```

Comment: you have only a list of Strings to write, do you want 1 String per line, or all on the same line? or add a new line with the data every time you call the method?

Comment: Add new line with data every time I made call to method

Comment: I added an answer for it below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you do it, you create a new workbook every time you call the function and you just end up erasing the previous ones. Therefore you only get the result of the last call.

If you want to add a line at every call, do it this way, you need to have the row number and the workbook as class variables. Also you need to get hold of the sheet that you already created to append to it. or you are going to erase it too.

```
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {

      write_Excel("myFile.xls","sheetName",
          Arrays.asList("value 1", "value 2", "value 3"));

      write_Excel("myFile.xls","sheetName",
          Arrays.asList("value 4", "value 5", "value 6"));

    } catch(IOException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }

  private static int newRowIndex = 0;
  private static HSSFWorkbook workbook = new HSSFWorkbook();

  public static void write_Excel(String fileName, String sheetName, List<String> dataToWrite) throws IOException {
    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(fileName);

    // open or create sheet
    HSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheet(sheetName) != null ?
        workbook.getSheet(sheetName) :
        workbook.createSheet(sheetName);

    // create a new row
    HSSFRow row = sheet.createRow(newRowIndex ++);

    // write your data in the new row
    for (int colIndex = 0; colIndex < dataToWrite.size(); colIndex++) {
      HSSFCell cell = row.createCell(colIndex);
      cell.setCellValue(new HSSFRichTextString(dataToWrite.get(colIndex)));
    }

    workbook.write(fos);
    fos.flush();
    fos.close();
  }
```

Comment: I used the reference of this code still last index value is getting inserted into the excel

Comment: I tested this code, and it writes 2 lines in the xls file.

Comment: In this case 2 rows get created but 1st rows is blank.

Comment: can you edit your post with your modified code so I can have a look?

Comment: Cool ! Welcome.

Answer (score 1):

You should add this line into for loop

```
  HSSFRow row = sheet.createRow(a++);
```